# Content delivery network

Tags: image, azure, cdn

Is there any CDN service where we don't have to upload images manually, 
It should get the image from original source (my site) site on first request and add it in storage for the next request. Note: My website in written in ASP.Net

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, then the Azure CDN already does this (as does pretty much any CDN provider).  You can configure the CDN to point to your website, and then when users access the CDN URL the CDN will fetch the content from your website and then cache it within the CDN storage.  The next request from a user in that same CDN region will get the file directly from CDN without going to your website.

See the "Caching content from hosted services" section in this [article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cdn-overview/).

Answer (score 0):

When setting up CDN on Windows Azure you configure it to point to a storage account. If you extend your application to save images to blob storage rather than local file system these images will be available via your CDN endpoint without any further work.

Answer (score 0):

If you store your image on your own origin server, you don't have to upload images manually to CDN. The CDN will get the image from your original server on first request and cache it in its edge server (not storage) for the next request.

If instead you store your image on CDN storage, you will then have to upload image to CDN storage so that it can be cached on CDN edge server upon first request.

All CDNs do the same for the above.